# disable ipad scroll of web app view

Tags: jquery, ipad, cordova, ios-simulator

I have been trying several times to solve an issue in my ipad application without success. I have a web application based on phonegap 1.3, the application is scrolling when i move my finger, it is ugly to see. I found some solutions which disable the scrolling for all:

```
window.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

My deal is to disable scrolling of the application itself from ipad. and not all elements as i need to scroll in some elements inside pages.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.

This was the solution:

By adding this line in **webViewDidFinishLoad** method:  ( see **AppDelegate.m** or **MainViewController.m** file in your xcode *classes folder*)

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView 
{
       ........................
       ........................

          theWebView.scrollView.bounces = NO;

       ........................
       ........................
}
```